# Hypothesis testing for A/B

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am an aspiring data scientist and I have tried understanding hypothesis testing for A/B testing (split testing) for a while and i have gone through countless videos on Youtube (since I am a visual learner) to get this understanding." I know how it works when it comes to one sample hypothesis testing, but I can't really wrap my head around it when it comes to 2 sample testing. Can someone please explain this as simply as possible?

Comment: First, I don't think you can really learn statistics by watching YouTubes, regardless of whether you are a visual learner. *Maybe* you can learn it just through books, if you are dedicated enough and smart enough, and a good starting book is Statistics by Freedman Pisani and Purves. But better to get a degree in statistics or at least take courses.

Second, A/B testing of what?  It could be almost anything. You might be comparing means, or counts, or survival time, or a dichotomous variable or ..... anything, and the method might be a t-test, chi-sqaure, Mann Whitney U, or something else.

Comment: I think net-positive learning can come from watching YouTube videos about statistics (e.g. I found Richard McElreath's [Statistical Rethinking](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDcUM9US4XdPz-KxHM4XHt7uUVGWWVSus) useful), but I would agree with Peter that it comes with substantial challenges to learn statistics solely guided by what you can think to search and what the YouTube algorithm thinks you'll watch. Sometimes it pays to get into some 'boring' technical math which you may only appreciate sometime later when disparate pieces start coming together.

Comment: thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

So a one-sample hypothesis test is a statistical test used to check if a specified value is equal to the mean of a distribution of that same variable collected by a researcher e.g. someone randomly suggests that all doctors make `$100,000` in Florida, a researcher goes and samples salaries of `200` doctors in Florida, gets the mean and uses a hypothesis test like the t-test to test if the mean of the `200` doctors is statistically significant from `$100,000` or not.

It's the same with 2 sample hypothesis testing but since you have mentioned AB testing I'll use an example that helped me when I was starting out.

Most A/B tests compare two versions of the same thing e.g. two versions of a website where the colour of the homepage is blue vs green(the version you are testing). There is a control, A, and a test variant, B(where the change is made), and the main question is "Is the mean of A (mA) different from the mean of B (mB)?". If they are not, then the difference between the means is 0 and if they are then the difference is not 0.

In a 2-sided AB test for example, what happens is that the distribution for both A and B are obtained, the difference of their means |mA-mB| is calculated and that value is converted to a standard normal value (i.e.it is standardized). This standardized value is then compared to zero on a standard normal distribution to see how far this computed mean falls from 0. If the mean falls outside the region of rejection (which is directly computed using the significance level you have chosen, say, 95%) then we say that "indeed! The difference between mA and mB is big enough to be statistically significant BECAUSE that difference is quite far from 0."

I will include some graphs in due time but this is a basic, simplified version of a two-sided A/B test. there are several resources you could use to get started on understanding A/B testing. One of which is a book called 'Controlled Online Experiments' that breaks it down quite nicely. You need to have a basic understanding of p-values, confidence levels, etc.

The main thing is, one-sample hypothesis tests do not test a difference between means of 2 samples, while two-sample A/B tests do!

Comment: thank you so much! This is great! I have also heard of this book before. Diagrams would really help to visualise it but honestly speaking, I think I was trying to wrap my mind around the way the difference is compared. I thought we just compared the  means of A and B but knowing that it's the difference makes a lot of sense. It puts things the videos into perspective now. Thank you so much!